# Sort and count number of occurrence of lines

Tags: command-line, sort

I have `Apache` logfile, `access.log`, how to count number of line occurrence in that file? for example the result of `cut -f 7 -d ' ' | cut -d '?' -f 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` is

```
a.php
b.php
a.php
c.php
d.php
b.php
a.php
```

the result that I want is:

```
3 a.php
2 b.php
1 d.php # order doesn't matter
1 c.php
```

Comment: `| sort | uniq -c`

Comment: `| LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -c`

Comment: ah I never knew that `uniq` could do that..

Comment: Do you have an example of the line in the log, as i think this could all be done with awk without all the pipes.

Comment: it's ok, 8.1GB log file processed in about 2 minutes, and it's done for now, no longer need this anymore :3

Comment: Asked one year earlier here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15984414/322020

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, sort using C locale is 10 times faster on my machine! Thanks

Answer (score 445, accepted):

```
| sort | uniq -c
```

As stated in the comments.

Piping the output into `sort` organises the output into alphabetical/numerical order.

This is a requirement because `uniq` only matches on repeated lines, ie

```
a
b
a
```

If you use `uniq` on this text file, it will return the following:

```
a
b
a
```

This is because the two `a`s are separated by the `b` - they are not consecutive lines. However if you first sort the data into alphabetical order first like

```
a
a
b
```

Then `uniq` will remove the repeating lines. The `-c` option of `uniq` counts the number of duplicates and provides output in the form:

```
2 a
1 b
```

References:

- [`sort(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)
- [`uniq(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux :) Don't hesitate to add more details to your answer and explain why and how this works ;)

Comment: `printf '%s\n' ①.php ②.php | sort | uniq -c` gives me `2 ①.php`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thats because the printf prints `php\nphp`

Comment: @Jidder, no, that's because `①.php` sorts the same as `②.php` in my locale because no sorting order is defined for those `①` and `②` character in my locale. If you want _unique_ values for any byte values (remember file paths are not necessarily text), then you need to fix the locale to C: `| LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -c`.

Comment: In order to have the resulting count file sorted you should consider adding the "sort -nr" as @eduard-florinescu answers below.

Answer (score 240):

```
[your command] | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

The accepted answer is almost complete you might want to add an extra `sort -nr` at the end to sort the results with the lines that occur most often first

**uniq** options:

```
-c, --count
       prefix lines by the number of occurrences
```

**sort** options:

```
-n, --numeric-sort
       compare according to string numerical value
-r, --reverse
       reverse the result of comparisons
```

In the particular case were the lines you are sorting are numbers, you need use `sort -gr` instead of `sort -nr`, see [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170043/sort-and-count-number-of-occurrence-of-lines/263849#comment922667_263849)

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know about `-n` option.

Comment: Great answer, here's what I use to get a wordcount out of file with sentences: `tr ' ' '\n' < $FILE | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > wordcount.txt`. The first command replaces spaces with newlines, allowing for the rest of the command to work as expected.

Comment: Using the options above I get "     1" before "  23344". Using `sort -gr` instead solves this. `-g`: compare according to general numerical value (instead of `-n`: compare according to string numerical value).

Comment: @PeterJaric Great catch and very useful to know about `-gr` but I think the output of `uniq -c` will be as such that  `sort -nr` will work as intended

Comment: Actually, when the data are numbers, `-gr` works better. Try these two examples, differing only in the g and n flags: `echo "1 11 1 2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` and `echo "1 11 1 2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr`. The first one sorts incorrectly, but not the second one.

Comment: @you are right, this is a corner case but I will mention it in the answer

Comment: `sort -g` and `sort -n` give me the same output for the given example on coreutils 9.1 (also tested with LC_ALL=C).

Answer (score 26):

You can use an associative array on **awk** and then -optionally- **sort**:

```
$ awk ' { tot[$0]++ } END { for (i in tot) print tot[i],i } ' access.log | sort
```

output:

```
1 c.php
1 d.php
2 b.php
3 a.php
```

Comment: How would you count the number of occurrences as the pipe is sending data?

Comment: This approach is very valuable if the input list is very large, because it does not require reading the entire list into memory and then sorting it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [clickhouse-client](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/utilities/clickhouse-local/) tool for working with files like with a sql table with a single column in this case:

```
clickhouse-local --query \
"select data, count() from file('access.log', TSV, 'data String') group by data order by count(*) desc limit 10"
```

My brief experiment shows it's about 50 times faster than

```
cat access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head 10
```

Comment: XD this is very cool use case of Clickhouse!

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 sample for `d.php`. So you'll get nice output like this.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file | sort | uniq -c
      3 a.php
      2 b.php
      1 c.php
      1 d.php
wolf@linux:~$
```

What happens when there is 4 `d.php`?

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file | sort | uniq -c
      3 a.php
      2 b.php
      1 c.php
      4 d.php
wolf@linux:~$
```

If you want to sort the output by the number of occurrence, you might want to send the stdout to `sort` again.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file | sort | uniq -c | sort
      1 c.php
      2 b.php
      3 a.php
      4 d.php
wolf@linux:~$
```

Use `-r` for reverse

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
      4 d.php
      3 a.php
      2 b.php
      1 c.php
wolf@linux:~$
```

Hope this example helps

Comment: duplicated answer of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263849/72456

Comment: what @αғsнιη comments, it is even superior, this one here is missing.