# Bash - sort and uniq on array

Tags: bash, command-line, sort, array, uniq

This is a similar question to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170043/sort-and-count-number-of-occurrence-of-lines)

I want to do the word count but this time, using an array.

For example, I have the following IPs inside a bash array called `IPS`.

```
IPS=("1.1.1.1" "5.5.5.5" "3.3.3.3" "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "5.5.5.5" "1.1.1.1")
```

If I read its contents:

```
user@server~$ "${IPS[*]}"
1.1.1.1 5.5.5.5 3.3.3.3 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 5.5.5.5 1.1.1.1
```

I would like to have something similar to this:

```
3 1.1.1.1
2 5.5.5.5
1 3.3.3.3
1 2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
printf '%s\n' "${IPS[@]}" |sort |uniq -c |sort -rn |sed 's/^ *//'
3 1.1.1.1
2 5.5.5.5
1 3.3.3.3
1 2.2.2.2
```

---

related:

- [Printing an array to a file with each element of the array in a new line in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125632/72456)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/72456)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an associative array to store the different IPS as keys which will increment when iterating over the IPS array.

```
#!/bin/bash
IPS=("1.1.1.1" "5.5.5.5" "3.3.3.3" "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "5.5.5.5" "1.1.1.1")
declare -A arr
for ip in ${IPS[@]};
do
        ((arr[${ip}]++))
done
for k in ${!arr[@]};
do
        echo "${arr[$k]} $k"
done | sort -rn
```

Comment: Note that that `((arr[${ip}]++))` is an _arbitrary command execution_ vulnerability if the contents of `$ip`/`$IPS` is not under your control (try for instance `ip='$(uname>&2)x' bash -c 'typeset -A arr; ((arr[${ip}]++))'`). You'd want `arr[$ip]=$((${arr[$ip]} + 1))` here to avoid it.