# I wanted to count all the words exist in a text file and its occerence saperately

Tags: text-processing

I have a file: `file.txt` with the following content:

```
I am groot, groot me, me groot,I love groot, groot groot, am I groot groot so
```

I wanted to count all the words individually.

I used command for single word count:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt | grep "groot" | wc -l
```

But I wanted to know is there any way to count all the words once? The desired output would look like this:

```
word        count
I           4
am          3
groot       8
me          2
```

Can it be done using some bash file or bash script? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort and count number of occurrence of lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170043/sort-and-count-number-of-occurrence-of-lines)

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
grep -o '\w\+' file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Explanation:

- `grep -o` will output each match on a separate line.
- `\w\+` matches any run of consecutive alphanumeric characters and `_`.
- `uniq -c` will output a count of occurrences for each consecutive run
  of repeated lines.
- The `sort` before `uniq -c` is necessary in order
  to group each unique word in a single consecutive run of repeated lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using only standard tools:

```
$ tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '\n' <file | sort | uniq -c
   3 I
   2 am
   8 groot
   1 love
   2 me
   1 so
```

This first replaces every non-word character with a newline character.  We define a non-word character as "any character that is not an alphabetic character" (this is what `-c` together with `[:alpha:]` and `\n` does on the `tr` command line).  Any run of more than one consecutive newline resulting from  this is compressed down to a single newline (this is what `-s` does on the `tr` command line).

The generated words (there will be one word per line) are then sorted with `sort` and the number of times each word occurs is then counted.

The `sort | uniq -c` part of the pipeline could be made slightly more time efficient with a single `awk` program:

```
$ tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '\n' <file | awk '{ count[$0]++ } END { for (word in count) print count[word], word }'
1 love
8 groot
2 am
3 I
1 so
2 me
```

The `awk` code simply uses each word read from `tr` as a key into the `count` associative array, and increments the associated value each time the word is seen. At the end, the code prints the counts for all words.

Comment: This is what I requred brother. Thank you smuch... You are awesome.... :)